# Darboux integrability implies Riemann integrability in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration, multiple-integral, riemann-sum

There have been multiple posts regarding the connection between Darboux & Riemann integrability, but most of them are only proofs for $\mathbb{R}$. The proof generally uses the following idea:

Let $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. If a bounded function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Darboux integrable, then by the definition of supremum and infimum, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some partition $P_0=\{x_0=a,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{N-1}, x_{N}=b\}$ such that
$$
U(f,P_0)<\inf_P U(f,P) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
L(f,P_0)>\sup_P L(f,P) - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
$$

Then, by choosing $\delta=\min\left\{x_1-x_0, x_2-x_1, \dots, x_N-x_{N-1}, \frac{\varepsilon}{2M(N-1)}\right\}$, we can show that $f$ is also Riemann integrable.

The $N-1$ in the denominator is to account for the (at most) $N-1$ intervals in the new partition $P'$ (where $|P'|<\delta$) which are not a subset of any interval in the original partition $P_0$. The $N-1$ was derived from the fact that there are $N-1$ points in $P_0$ that is strictly between $a$ and $b$ (i.e. $|P_0\cap(a,b)|=N-1$).

However, this method of proof does not translate well into higher dimension, $\mathbb{R}^n$. At $n\ge2$, we no longer have the luxury of just considering the finite $N-1$ points; instead, we will have to reckon with an infinite number of points. For $n=2$, this will be a line; for $n=3$, this will be a plane; for even higher dimension, it will be hyperplane but either way, infinite number of points.

As such, we can no longer choose a reasonable $\delta>0$. Any solution I can think of to fix this leads to some form of circular argument, whereby we need $\delta$ to defined $P'$ but we need number of intervals in $P'$ to define $\delta$. So how do I reconcile and salvage this proof to show that Darboux integrability implies Riemann integrability in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

P.S. Rather than providing a totally different way of approaching this proof (e.g. consider integral about each of the $n$ directions separately), I would appreciate if the answers point out how to salvage this discrepancy or why there is no way to reconcile this discrepancy.

Comment: In higher dimensions, you work with the *mesh* of the partition (the diameter of the largest subrectangle).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but changing the idea of _length_ into _mesh_ still will not solve the issue at hand.

Comment: No, you consider the hyperplanes that form the partition. You don't think of them as individual sets of points. You might want to know the total "area" ($(n-1)$-dimensional volume) of the dividing hyperplanes.

Comment: I think I kind of get it, but maybe not exactly. So if we let the "area" be $A$, does it mean we choose $\delta=\min\{\dots,\frac{\varepsilon}{2MA}\}$ instead?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are asking how to prove if $f$ is integrable over a rectangle $R \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ in the sense that both upper and lower Darboux integrals are equal to $I$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if the partition mesh $\|P\| < \delta$ then $|S(P,f) - I| < \epsilon$ for any Riemann sum $S(P,f)$ (i.e., with any choice of partition tags). Correct?

Comment: Yes sir, that is correct.